# How to specify a set of strings in bash command arguments

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to use a type of set notation in a bash command and can't find the answer anywhere. I want to do something like:

```
cp combined.[txt|jpg|pdf] ~
```

Where this will copy all files, named combined, with txt jpg or pdf endings.

How can I do this?

Comment: cp *.combined.{txt,jpg,pdf} ~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your description, it sounds like you want:

```
cp combined.{txt,jpg,pdf} ~
```

But I may be misunderstanding you. I'm not sure why you wrote `*.combined` instead of `combined`, given that your description simply says that the files are "named combined".

Either way, see [the *Bash Reference Manual*, §3.1 "Brace Expansion"](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion), for more information.

Comment: Ah, that's exactly what I needed! Thank you. The *. was a mistake.  My bad.  I will edit and remove.  Thanks again.